# Updating custom theme that is built from scratch

Tags: themes

Is there any way to update theme from backend? I tried but wordpress shows error that folder already exists and renaming zip file creates and installs completely new theme(Which is another issue as I want to maintain version numbers on zip file names).

Anything I can do so wordpress will understand that I want to update existing theme instead of treating it as new theme? It will be better if I can update it from backend rather than go through ftp.

Comment: When you say "backend", do you mean backend as in the sever or WP admin dashboard?

Comment: WP Admin dashboard

Comment: You can probably use WP-Editor plugin and upload the files individually from Appearance -> Theme Editor Plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-editor/

Comment: Tried that but I would rather use ftp than update each file from editor. It is easier to just upload zip file and extract but I wanted to be able to do it from dashboard so you don't have to go through ftp login etc. Thanks

Comment: Just use FTP and overwrite the folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now I suggest simply uploading it via FTP. If you're not too familiar, many hosts offer "WebFTP" which is usually easier to use.

For the future you might consider [GitHub Updater](https://github.com/afragen/github-updater), check out their [wiki](https://github.com/afragen/github-updater/wiki). This basically allows you to use a new setting in style.css

```
GitHub Plugin URI: foo/bar
```

Once configured, you can use versioning on GitHub and simply update from the backend, like you're used to from other plugins & themes.

Comment: Is that original Git repository? I remember coming across it when I was looking for that solution but repository I came across wasn't updated for 2 years I guess. Or maybe I am confusing it with something else.Well this seems the only solution. Thanks.

Comment: To be honest I don't have any experience with this my own, but it is quite active with multiple contributors, so you're probably safe to use it